# Java: How can I make a clone of a HashMap of ArrayList ?

Tags: java, clone

In my problem, I created an object `HashMapOfArrayList`. It has an instance method named `transformation`, which essentially remove and add edges.

Problem lies in my Testing Class. I want to create a clone of the original Object (i.e. the graph I have  when I load the text file) at each iteration. I do not know how to do this. And I think reading in the file again in each iteration, which is what I have now, is really inefficient. How should I create a clone in this situation ?

```
class HashMapOfArrayList{
     HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> my_graph;

     // constructor
     public HashMapOfArrayList(){
                my_graph = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
     }
      .......
}

class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        HashMapOfArrayList graph = new HashMapOfArrayList();
        graph.read_file_and_populate("file.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ 
// Need a way to clone the object instead of reading in the file many times.
                HashMapOfArrayList graph = new HashMapOfArrayList();
                graph.read_file_and_populate("file.txt");
                graph.transformation();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new constructor that takes your HashMapOfArrayList as an argument, and then all you need to do is clone the Integers in the ArrayList.

```
public HashMapOfArrayList(HashMapOfArrayList source) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph = source.getGraph(); // get the source graph

    my_graph = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(); //define our graph 
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : graph.entrySet()) {
        //iterate through the graph
        ArrayList<Integer> sourceList = entry.getValue();
        ArrayList<Integer> clonedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        clonedList.addAll(sourceList);
        //put value into new graph
        my_graph.put(entry.getKey(), clonedList);
    }
}
```

Then, you can replace your original read with the cloning constructor and transform it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ 
    HashMapOfArrayList clone = new HashMapOfArrayList(graph);
    clone.transformation();
}
```

Comment: getGraph() is an instance method that returns the object itself right ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF yes it returns source' my_graph.

Comment: There's no need to clone the integers - Integer is immutable, so you can just do clonedList.addAll(sourceList).

Comment: @SBodd Good to know. I'll update the code. Wasn't sure about that one.

Comment: @Compass Why do we need the `sourceList` and `clonedList` ? Because I thought `entry.getValue()` is an `ArrayList<Integer>` and just do `my_graph.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());`. And why are we not doing the sourceList and clonedList thing for `entry.getKey()`. I know I am probably wrong. But what am I missing here ?

Comment: @mynameisJEFF If you do don't use a clonedList, any changes made to the cloned map's arraylist will affect the source map's arraylist as well (we pass references to objects, not objects). The key itself is immutable since it is stored as a value rather than as a reference.

Comment: @Compass I just realize we could simplify it to one line `ArrayList<Integer> cloned_list = new ArrayList<Integer>(entry.getValue());` and it works . Correct me if I am wrong.